# Four fours to get $\pi$

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers, open-ended

[Four fours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_fours) is a famous puzzle (made trivial with logarithms). For this puzzle, we take inspiration from [Glen O's challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12325/making-%CF%80-from-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9/91156#91156) from a few years back. The rules here are slightly different, but the goal is the same. Your goal is to approximate $\pi$ to the highest accuracy (per operation) as possible, using only four fours and the following operations:

- The classic arithmetic operations: $+,-,\times,\div$
- Exponentiation and log-base as binary operations: $\log_a b$ and $a^b$. You may only take logs of positive real numbers.
- The root function as a binary operator $\sqrt[b]{a}$.
- Unary operations: $(\cdot)!$ for integer arguments only (so you can't use $\frac12!$ to get $\sqrt{\pi}/2$), unary negation $-$, the square root $\sqrt{\cdot}$, and floor/ceiling for rounding down/up: $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ and $\lceil \cdot\rceil$.

Any other operations are not allowed, including [double factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) and decimal points. In addition, you can do the following with no penalty:

- Parentheses (for grouping purposes only, no binomial coefficients etc.)
- Concatenation of 4's. That is, you can use 44 as a single number without costing an operation. You cannot concatenate things that are not fours, e.g. you can't concatenate $\sqrt{4}$ and $4!$ to get 224.
- You do not have to use all four fours (e.g. [msh210's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97895/four-fours-to-get-pi/97896#97896) of $\lfloor 4\rfloor$ is allowed).

Your score is equal to the number of digits of accuracy *per operation* used. That is, if you got the approximation $A$ by using $n$ operations, your score is $$
\frac{-\log_{10}|\pi - A|}{n}
$$
To avoid division by 0, you must use at least one operation.

---

As an example, if you submit $\sqrt{(44 - 4!)/4} = \sqrt{5}\approx 2.24$, that has 4 operations, so your score would be:$$
\frac{-\log_{10} |\pi - \sqrt{5}|}4 \approx 0.01438...
$$

Comment: It would be more appropriate to post this here, as the problem would probably get closed for 'lack of context' on Math SE.

Comment: If anyone can get $\log_2 (\sqrt{8} + 6) \approx 3.1422$ in $4$ operations, you would get a score of approximately $0.812$.

Comment: Are more than 4 fours allowed?

Comment: @zixuan No, you can only use up to 4 fours.

Comment: It would be very interesting to know how many fours and operations are needed for any given accuracy.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Three fours, five operations, score 1.0413

$$ \sqrt[4!]{4!}+\sqrt{4} \approx 3.141586 $$

Also five operations but too cute not to include, score 0.7539:

$$ \sqrt[4]{44\sqrt{\sqrt{4!}}} \approx 3.141423 $$

Four operations, score 0.7059:

$$ \sqrt4^\sqrt{\log_4{44}} \approx 3.143093 $$

The best three-operation expression has already been posted in another answer.

For completeness sake, two, score 0.4245:

$$ \left\lceil \log_4{44} \right\rceil = 3.0 $$

and one, score 0.3852:

$$ \log_4{44} \approx 2.729716. $$

<sub>This doesn’t seem to be the type of question that calls for spoiler hiding, correct me if I’m wrong.</sub>

Comment: That is extremely impressive!

Comment: "This doesn’t seem to be the type of question that calls for spoiler hiding" - all other answerers seem to disagree.

Answer (score 6):

> $$\frac{44}{\left\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{(4+4)!}}\right\rfloor}$$

is equal to

> the common approximation $22/7$

and scores

> $$\frac{-\log_{10}\left(\frac{22}7-\pi\right)}6$$

which is $\approx0.4830$.

---

*Edit:* Better yet is

> $$\sqrt{\frac{44-4}4}$$

which scores

> $$\frac{-\log_{10}\left(\sqrt{10}-\pi\right)}3$$

, or $\approx0.5614$.

Comment: Nice. But how did you score it- how many operations did you charge yourself? I count 4, but I think you may have calculated score with 3. And maybe the charge is 5?

Comment: @Damila, it looks like six operations to me. I think that's how I computed the score, but if I messed up then please let me know.

Comment: @Damila he did score it correctly

Comment: I missed the round down symbols.  Well done!

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I'll start us off with the obvious:

> $\lfloor4\rfloor$ scores $\approx0.0663$.

Surely that can be improved on….

Comment: Good start! Yes it can be improved on though. Since the question, the best I've got is about 0.2

Comment: Lol Nice observation

Answer (score 5):

Now I've got it ! Just finished generating all possible solutions for a given number of operations. Had to discard some answers because of float overflow so I hope big numbers means lower score.

Best scores up to 5 operations were found by Roman Odaisky and zixuan. Here's a solution for 6 operations :

> $\sqrt[4!]4!+4-\sqrt 4   = 3.14158644$

with a score of 0.86778360, but it's still less than the best 5-operation answer.

Program crashed pretty hard at 7 operations though.

[Here's the source code](https://gist.github.com/salel/94f0d55ef293cbf951a49902c67f0455).

## Old answer

I had an idea how to brute force the whole thing : concatenation is free, so why not use it to its full potential ? With $log_a$ or $\sqrt[b]a$, you'll get only 1 operation so a higher score, and with as many fours you want you might get to $\pi$.

I just realized while writing this that you need four fours or less, so my scores don't qualify.

I used python for precision (tried C++ first but FP64 isn't enough), and used a nested loop to generate numbers of concatenated fours $a$ and $b$, computed $log_b a$ and its score and returned the best score and values (it's $O(n^2)$ so I didn't push it too hard, took 5 minutes) so the best answer for $a$ and $b$ $< 10^{2000}$ is :

$A = 3.141596697042137$ with a score of $5.393247671097606$ for :

$log_b a$ with $a$ being 1680 concatenated fours and $b$ being 535 concatenated fours.

I'll try going at it later by brute forcing all possible operations though, with a acceptable amount of fours.

Comment: You can only use up to 4 fours.

Comment: Yes I realized this too late, but this gave me the motivation to work on brute forcing the original problem, which is a bit more complex. Still working on it.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

This isn't legal, but

> $\sqrt{4} \times \arccos(4-4) = \pi$

with a score of $+\infty$

Comment: Yes there's a reason I disallowed inverse trig functions / complex logarithms

Comment: :)  (extra characters to pad the comment)

Comment: @FlorianF Fewer operations ;)

Comment: $4 \times arctan(4/4)$ uses fewer operations, so it scores a larger infinity than yours. [grammar fixed]

Answer (score 3):

3.160964... in 4 operations, score 0.42820978

> $\log_{4}(4(4!-4)) $

Answer (score 2):

Got it down to 3.14 but it uses sin again:
Score: 1.38767676535

> 4+sin444 = 3.13991521562

Ok this is extremely close with 2 ops. (3.18):
Score: 0.71908465944

> ln(4!)=3.17805383035

I'm not sure if this is legal cuz it uses sin:
Score: 0.49654277813

> 4+sin(4)=3.24319750469

Very close approximation (3.1): 
Score: 0.44995372319

> 4-log(4+4)=3.09691001301

Really simple one lol works surprisingly well:
Score: 0.42447963952

> 4 - 4/4 = 3

Extremely close (3.16) but 4 operations
Score: 0.42108608415

> sqrt(4+4+sqrt4)=3.16227766017

This one is really close (3.18) but uses more operations:
Score: 0.33056528095

> sqrt4 + (4+4)th root(4)=3.189207115

Heres one with just one operation: 
Score: 0.29569382019

> log(4444)= 3.64777405027

Comment: It seems sin and ln and log with no explicit base are not legal.

Comment: @msh210 yeah probably

Comment: @Ankit indeed they are not.

Comment: but can you do log base 4?

Answer (score 2):

> $\sqrt[4]{4!*4} \approx 3.13016916015$

Only used $4-\frac{4}{4}$ operations and $4-\frac{4}{4}$ $4$s. Score:

> $0.64740035441$

*Please* allow this answer. I took $4$ hours to find this answer (or a very long time).

Answer (score 1):

If this is legal:

> 4/ (4!th root of 44)

Equals

> 3.416

With 3 operations

> Division, factorial, root. Parentheses not necessary, added for clarity without full mathematical notation.

For a score of 0.187

Comment: I didn't say roots were allowed, but this and one other answer are very creative. I'll allow it.

Comment: I have another answer.  Posted as a different answer. Got it down to 3.18

Answer (score 1):

Second answer, got it to 3.18 with 5 operations:

> 4 - SQRT(4*4/4!) = 3.1835

Score = 0.276