# Using only numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 and addition,make up to the sum 100.using numbers only once?

Tags: mathematics

Using only the numbers

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 0

**With only addition can you make a sum of 100?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 = 100](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11998/1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-100)

Comment: This is impossible since only addition is allowed.

Comment: Actually I think you can combine numbers like 3,4 can become 34

Comment: @OmegaKrypton No. The previous question allows many different operators; this one restricts to addition only.

Comment: why is there an addition tag?

Answer (score 6):

This is mathematically impossible. I think [EmbodimentofIgnorance was trying to tell us this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79042/using-only-numbers-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-and-addition-make-up-to-the-sum-100-using#comment-230975), but didn't explain it.

> Basically, no matter what order you try to put the answers into, it'll never actually become $100$ — it'll always be $99$, because the numbers add up to be multiples of nine. Consider this:
>
>  When you add up all numbers $0$–$9$, it'll be $45$ — a multiple of $9$.
>  Now obviously, $45$ is too small, so you're gonna have to make some two digit numbers (e.g. $45$, $67$, $13$, etc.)

Now this gets a little funky, so bear with me.

> Let's assume you use the value of $34$ instead of $3+4$. You'll notice that you'll get a multiple of nine when you subtract the number by the ones you were using (so $34-3-4=27$).

Now, going back to the total, it becomes $45-3-4+34 = 72$.

> You subtract the three and the four, because those numbers are being used for $34$. Keep in mind that order doesn't matter, because it's essentially just $45-7$.
>   No matter what pair you decide to choose, it'll always turn out to be a multiple of $9$.

Comment: AHHHHHH omg I swear I've been using se for a year now and I still can't use spoiler tags correctly. How do you put multiple of them without it glitching

Comment: you have to add some text between each separate tag. If you want to add a newline in a spoiler, add <br> but don't use "enter" or it will glitch. edit: looking at the edit, it seems there're several method to achieve this. apparently you can add a new spoiler tag on each newline to add multiline spoiler

Comment: Turns out this was a way more interesting problem than the question lets on.

Answer (score 4):

The closest I can get is this:

> 90 + 1,765 + 8,234 = 99,999
>
>  Like north said also only a multiple of 9