# 123456789 = 100 with three operations?

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, formation-of-numbers

Given the sequence 123456789

You can insert three operations (+,-,X,/) into this sequence to make the equation = 100.

Is there a way to solve this without brute force?

Comment: Can we use one operation multiple times?

Comment: I found  way to get 200  :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 = 100](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11998/1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-100)

Answer (score 2):

If I’m allowed to use the same operation multiple times, I would do:

> 123−45−67+89 = 100

Comment: you also need to re-order the digits to do that, so it's not a soltion

Comment: Thanks I found out using the correct order :)

Comment: @Jdrupal your answer With brute force, but I am looking for other possible solutions.. As I mentioned in question answer should be without Brute force.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by brute force?

Comment: @CR241 There’s absolutely no evidence of a brute force method being used here.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov it seems you don't know the meaning of Brute force?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search

Comment: @CR241 The definition of brute force is "relying on or achieved through the application of force, effort, or power in usually large amounts instead of more efficient, carefully planned, or precisely directed methods" according to the Merriam-Webster dictionary. Therefore, it is hard to tell whether a brute force method was used here. Plus, this is an answer that can be found all over the internet.